# Netlogo - position the label at the center

Tags: netlogo

How to position the agent label at the center of the agent?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetLogo doesn't offer fine-tuning of label positioning directly.

If you absolutely need to control this, you can create a separate turtle, set its label, give the turtle an empty shape, and then position the turtle precisely.

If you use `tie`, you can even make the label-turtle follow the parent turtle around automatically.